# Unconfiguring constant relaunch of application

Tags: daemon, application-launch

A long time ago I had configured on OSX that if a certain app crashes, it should be restarted directly again. Now, I don't know where I had configured that. And I'd like to unconfigure this.

I've already looked into the Launch Deamons and Agents (system and user). And I can't find anything there. The parent process is "launchd" (PID=1).

Do you have any suggestions how to find out where I have configured this? Do you know any ways to find out which line of code/configuration achieves the relaunching?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve with the following command:

```
sudo launchctl procinfo {PID}
```

Then it will say which configuration under "path" causes this program to be launched over and over again. Unfortunately I couldn't find it as i had a typo in the config.